# Jetpack compose internal compiler arguments warning

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have created a brand new android application using compose 1.0.1 and Kotlin 1.5.20 and I am getting this warning during compilation:

```
w: ATTENTION!
This build uses unsafe internal compiler arguments:

-XXLanguage:+NonParenthesizedAnnotationsOnFunctionalTypes

This mode is not recommended for production use,
as no stability/compatibility guarantees are given on
compiler or generated code. Use it at your own risk!
```

You can reproduce it by creating a brand new empty compose activity project in Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 and running `./assembleDebug`. It also happens on any other android studio project when compose is added

Should I be worried about this warning? Given this warning, is Compose ready for production yet?

Answer (score 7):

Compose is definitely production ready, that is why it is launched on the stable channel now. As far as the warning is concerned, I think you need not worry about it. I have seen this issue in previous versions and it got fixed eventually. It might have recurred, but I guess since it is `internal`, there's not much you can do about it. Long as it does not prevent you from developing further, it's ok. Chill

Comment: Got this warning today. But looks like I need not worry and I can just `Chill`

Comment: Is 'Chill' a Composable? Why did you use code formatting? Show your support via an up-vote!!

Comment: Cheers! First answer with 5 upvotes!!

Comment: I upvoted the question. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: But I didn't receive anything yet

Comment: Oh I think you upvoted the question instead.

Comment: The question is not mine.

Comment: Yeah, saw that.

Comment: So kindly change that.

Comment: Upvoted. Happy? :)

Comment: Yep. Happier than ever.